# How to open a pdf file using itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext

I want to open a existing PDF document in my hard disk.How can I open a PDF document and view it with itextsharp? Or do i have to use adobe PDF reader component to view PDF.

If I use adobe PDF reader component to view PDF document, is it possible to use feature of itextsharp such as split/merge documents, extract images?
I'm using c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iTextSharp is not a viewer, hence it is not possible to open a PDF document using iTextSharp if you want to view the document the way you would view it in Adobe Reader. There is a Windows based GUI to open documents with iText (it's called [iText RUPS](http://itextpdf.com/product/itext_rups)), but it will show you what's *inside* the PDF document, not what is visible on the *outside*.

So the answer to your question *do i have to use Adobe Reader component to view PDF?* is YES!

However, Adobe Reader is a viewer, not a tool to split/merge documents. You need Adobe Acrobat if you want to split/merge documents.

One can copy/paste an image from a PDF using Adobe Acrobat or Reader *manually* (for instance by selecting the image, right-clicking and selecting *Save as image*), but the EULA of those doesn't allow you to do this from code. They are end user *desktop* products. You can not use them on a server or inside another application.

Comment: So I should use adobe reader component to view a document.That is okay.I want to implement those features in my application.So can i use those features using itextsharp to a PDF document opened using adobe reader component?

Comment: When a document is opened in Adobe Reader, it can't be accessed by any other software: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29590590/1622493 (Moreover: how would you control iTextSharp from Adobe Reader? Please reconsider your design and rephrase your question.)